# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value into int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, data-conversion

I have the following problem. 
There is conversion problem in my database and this is a message I receive

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1589698' to data type int.
```

It's unusual because there is no extra signs and I work with these data for a long time but suddenly my procedures stopped working today.  I tried to use convert and cast. I tried to retyped the number and each time I have the following error.

Comment: how does the conversion looks like? can you show the part using `CONVERT` and / or `CAST` ?

Comment: There needs to be far more detail in this I'm afraid. That value is perfectly valid as an `int`, so we can't really help you. Are you sure that field doesn't contain any hidden characters, like a linefeed for example? This can happen if you are importing data from Excel for example.

Comment: hi i have try DECLARE @varr varchar(50) = '1589698' 

SELECT cast (@varr as INT) and it's work in my case

Comment: @SebastianBrosch just like that   `convert(int, atr_value)`  `convert(atr_value as int)`

Comment: @Astroc - can you show the relevant part of your code so we can reproduce the issue. As @DavidG mentioned the value `1589698` is a valid `INT`!

Comment: @DavidG I import this data from another system and this is probably a cause of the problem. Unfortunately I can't edit it anyway. My proc just imports this data from linked server and bulks into my table. I pasted this data to excel and it sees the value as number. Just pasted the number to browser and recieved such output  '1589698' prntscr.com/mhc5ug

Comment: Look at that [screenshot](https://prntscr.com/mhc5ug), it clearly tells you there's an extra character on the end...

Comment: @DavidG Yep it looks that a hidden sign somehow was appended to a value. I just uploaded the cell with a number and my procedures work but I wonder how it happened. Thank you for help!

Comment: @pascalsanchez some hidden sign somehow was appended to my value. I already fixed it by uploading the record. Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 2):

As shown by this screenshot:

[image]

you have an errant character on the end of the `varchar` column. That character is what causes the conversion to fail.

You need to do two things:

1. Remove that character to allow the process to work again.
2. Always validate your input! This value should never have made it into your database in the first place.

Comment: Yep. I use this proc for a long time and once I had a problem with extra tabs and now with hidden charss. I must definetly make some validations in my importing procedures. Thank you for reply